# Why can't I get the alert to show?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, alert, cs50

I have been trying to use an alert as a way to tell the user that a given username has already been registered but the alert message isn't displayed.

So, the idea is that on registration the username is sent to python where it will be checked if the username already exists if so the code will return `jsonify(False)`. Then in javascript, it should display an alert message if the return is `false`. But my code doesn't work.

**Python:**

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
       """Return true if username available, else false, in JSON format"""
username = request.args.get("username")
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=username)
if len(rows) >= 1 or len(username) < 1:
    return jsonify(False)
else:
    return jsonify(True)
```

**HTML:**

```
form action="/register" onsubmit="validateUsername()" method="post" id ="register">
        div class="form-group">
            input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        /div>
        div class="form-group">
            input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        /div>
        div class="form-group">
            input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        /div>
        button class="btn btn-primary" id="submittion" type="submit">Register
    /form>
    script>
       let username = document.querySelector('input[name=username]');
       document.getElementById("submittion").addEventListener("click",function() {
            $.get('/check?username=' + username.value, function(data) {
                if (data==false){
                    data.preventDefault();
                    alert("Username is not available!");
                }
                else {
                   alert("not working");
                }
            });
        });
```

`</script>`

When data is submitted, the user should be alerted that the username already exists.

*PS: I know I left some of the `<` out in order to show my HTML code properly.*

Comment: you do not cancel the submit action so it submits the page. You also do not have an error handler so no way to know if the Ajax call fails

Comment: @epascarello so I need to put a 4th parameter for error? also cancelling submission I stop it by the part    data.preventDefault();. shouldn't that do it? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request is send on submit, but it doesn't have enough time to receive a response before the form is submitted. To prevent the form from submitting you can use [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
document.getElementById("submittion").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // The ajax call
});
```

**Update**

You probably want to listen to form `submit` event instead of button `click` (e.g. for keyboard support). That said, the problem here is that the submit handler needs to "wait" for the async ajax check.

To make this work you could keep track if the user was checked and do a resubmit while disabling the check (untested code below):

```
const form = document.getElementById("register");
const username = form.querySelector("input[name=username]");
let checkUser = true;

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  if (checkUser) {
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check the username
    $.get("/check?username=" + username.value, function (data) {
      if (data === false) {
        alert("Username is not available!");
      } else {
        // Resubmit the form without the user check
        checkUser = false;
        form.submit();
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  // Reset the variable for the next check
  checkUser = true;
});
```

**Alternative**

You could also post straight to the `/register` route (via ajax) and perform the validation/checks there. When everything is ok you can register the the user and return true, otherwise return false when check fails:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // Prevent the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // Post the form data
  $.post(form.action, form.serialize(), function(data) {
    if (data === false) {
      // Register failed
      alert("Username is not available!");
    } else {
      // Register successfull
      window.location.replace("/welcome");
    }
  });
});
```

And maybe you can try to avoid JavaScript after all by performing all logic serverside, and render the template with form errors. But that's beyond the scope of this question ;)

Comment: okay it does work now and shows alert but how do I prevent the data from being submitted because when I remove the alert message data is still submitted.

Comment: @Mashaal I get what you mean, I've updated the answer.